# Memory usage analysis

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

I was performing an activity wherein i had to calculate the total memory used by the system, and then give the accounting for the total used memory in terms of processes and other entities.

I used /proc/meminfo to get total used memory (Total Usable Mem - Total Free Mem).
Then listed out all the processes and there individual memory usage.
But both figures didnt match which was not what I expected to be. 
Even with the total memory used by all processes I was not able to get account for 7MB to used memory.

Am I missing any piece of information here ?

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that you <sup>`<quote>`</sup>listed out all the processes and there [sic] individual memory usage<sup>`</quote>`</sup> using `ps` you might be looking at

> [The SIZE and RSS fields don't count some parts of a process including the page
>   tables, kernel stack, struct thread_info, and struct task_struct. This is
>   usually at least 20 KiB of memory that is always resident. SIZE is the virtual
>   size of the process (code+data+stack).](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps)

Comment: also there's the problem of correctly charging for shared memory. (and shared sections of page table)

Answer (score 0):

Shared libraries can mess up the figures. Processes can share memory directly. Some sections of memory are quietly reserved for hardware I/O mapping or other OS internals.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense for the difference to be (a lot) bigger then, really. Are you referring to 'zero-copy' buffers? These are actually allocated and owned by the user process. (_The kernel is just informed to keep the pages locked and remaps the address into kernel space IIRC_).